# The limit superior of $|\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^k|^{1/k}$ where $x_i\in\mathbb{C}$

Tags: matrices, limits, complex-numbers, limsup-and-liminf

I am thinking about the following questions:

> $A$ is a complex $n\times n$ matrix, $\rho(A)$ means the spectral radius of $A$, $\operatorname{tr}(A)$ means the trace of $A$, then prove:
> $$ \varlimsup_{k\to\infty} \big( |\operatorname{tr}(A^k)|^{1/k} \big) = \rho(A). $$

It is clearly equivalent to
$$ \varlimsup_{k\to\infty} \left| \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^k \right|^{1/k} = \max_{1\le i\le n} |x_i|, \quad x_i\in\mathbb{C}, i=1,\cdots,n. $$
When every $x_i\in\mathbb{R}$, it is easy. But when all of $x_i$ are complex, I can only obtain
$$ \varlimsup_{k\to\infty} \left| \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^k \right|^{1/k} \le \max_{1\le i\le n} |x_i|. $$
Any hint?

Comment: Where does the question come from?

Comment: @MartinR <Linear and Nonlinear Functional Analysis with Applications> by P. G. Ciarlet, the question is come from the problem 2.9-3.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, that is actually what I want! Thank you!

Comment: Found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Climsup_%7Bk%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cleft%7C%20%5Csum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5En%20x_i%5Ek%20%5Cright%7C%5E%7B1%2Fk%7D%20%5Cle%20%5Cmax_%7B1%5Cle%20i%5Cle%20n%7D%20%7Cx_i%7C.%24)

Comment: @MartinR Thank you! Many times, I couldn't find the question here, asked the question and eventually closed as duplicate. With approacho, it is easier to search.